# SMS from apple phone number (Imessage) not being delivered to twilio python app hosted on aws lambda

Tags: python, lambda, twilio

Context: I've recently re-authorised a twilio account with valid numbers which is linked to my AWS lambda instance running a simple Python script to respond to sms messages. I set this up successfully a year ago and it was able to respond to sms messages from both android and apple phones but recent tests have shown that it can receive and respond to sms messages from android phones but not apple phones.

What has changed: I have edited the Python script with an extra conditional based off my existing code, re-deployed the API on aws lambda and created a new twilio number which the lambda application is hooked up to for and I have made sure the twilio number I am sending sms to is the newly updated number.

Where it works and crashes: I am able to send sms messages from android phones which respond to them as expect. It comes up in the twilio log with the incoming message and outgoing messages as expected however when I send an sms message from an apple phone (imessage) it states that the message was not delivered and there is no mention in the twilio log of receiving any text from imessage. This did not occur when sending messages to the old number I had registered with my twilio account.

Already tried: The numbers I am receiving texts from are authorised, I re-authorised the apple number I am working with. The twilio number is registered as a landline UK number and I am sending messages from UK phone numbers, this process works with Android numbers but not apple numbers.

Desired solution: A method or code change in either AWS lambda/ twilio which will enable sms from apple phones.

EDIT: Below is a stripped back variant of my code. This function was working with the original number but no more.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if "zero" in event["Body"]:
        return '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>'\
               '<Response><Message>zero</Message></Response>'
    elif "1" in event["Body"]:
        return '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>'\
               '<Response><Message>1</Message></Response>'
    elif "2" in event["Body"]:
        return '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>'\
               '<Response><Message>2</Message></Response>'
    elif "3" in event["Body"]:
        return '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>'\
               '<Response><Message>3</Message></Response>'
    elif "4" in event["Body"]:
        return '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>'\
               '<Response><Message>4</Message></Response>'
    else:
        return '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>'\
               '<Response><Message>{}</Message></Response>'.format(event)
```

Comment: Can we not see the code? Per the help center, errors have to be reproducible. See: [mcve].

Comment: Code added into the main post.

Comment: Is the issue with iMessage, or just with SMS from any Apple device?

Comment: I've tried it from the only one I have access to and it's going through messages/imessage so I can't narrow that down.

Comment: Is the message bubble on the iPhone green or blue?

Comment: The colour is green.

Comment: Then it’s SMS, no need to worry about iMessage.